# JPEG compression method results in different output if on simulator vs device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I have been trying to reproduce an issue with my app where sometimes an image is deemed to be "blurry" by a user.  I tracked down an original image that had this issue and still could not reproduce it locally.  That is.. until I ran the exact same code on a real device vs the simulator.  To reproduce, I made a project with the following snippet:

```
    func compressImage() {
        let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "original", withExtension: "HEIC")!
        let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        print("Size of original is ", Double(imageData.count) / 1000.0)
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
        let jpgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)!
        print("Size of compressed is ", Double(jpgData.count) / 1000.0)
        let directory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) as NSURL
        try! jpgData.write(to: directory.appendingPathComponent("output.jpg")!)
    }
```

Ran this code on simulators for iPhone 11 Pro 13.4, iPhone 11 Pro 13.4, and iPhone 7+ 13.4

```
Size of original is  518.901
Size of compressed is  567.656
```

I then ran this on physical devices with the exact same models/iOS versions and got:

```
Size of original is  518.901
Size of compressed is  458.201
```

So the filesizes are quite different.  In comparing the output photos, they are also different.  Subtle but different in terms of colorspace and blurriness.

Sim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsdr1.jpg
Phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP95V.jpg

The difference may seem trivial, but if you download them and quickly flip between them you can see the difference.  And for my particular application one is out of acceptable range.

So what am I missing here?  Why would the exact same code produce different outputs?  I'm moving forward with only using a real device to test quality, but now I'm worried about my methods and am wondering if I should do compression with a lib or on the backend instead.

Comment: Your numbers for the simulator test indicate that the compressed image is larger than the original. Is this correct?

Comment: Unfortunately I was using an HEIC just for the purposes of this test as I wanted to drag in an asset.  If you use a PHAsset from your device the size would of course be smaller as you compress.  Results of inconsistencies across device/sim are the same.